# Handling quick succession of function calls - Javascript / underscore.js / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I'm looking for a way to call a different function if it's getting called in quick succession. The first call needs to go through as quick as possible though.

So far I've tried the `_.throttle` and `_.debounce` from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to handle that and it's almost what I'm looking for but not quite. I can delay the orignal function call with these, but I want to call an entire different one when multiple calls happen at once.

Is this possible or

example:

```
var _ = require("underscore")._;

function foo(){
   console.log("foo");
}

function bar(){
   console.log("bar");
}

var delayedFoo = _.throttle(foo, 1000);
```

instead throttle I want foo() to be called once and then bar() for the specified duration, before foo() can be called again:

```
var delayedFoo = _.route(foo, bar, 1000);
```

Is there a library or framework that has a built-in function like this?

Comment: So are you asking for a total of two function calls per "cycle" (`foo`, then `bar`, wait 1000ms, start over), or something else?  Just want to make sure I understand :)

Comment: Do you want to throttle or debounce (i.e. switch back to `foo` after the period counting from every call or from the first one only)?

Comment: @Bergi I want to switch back to foo after the waiting period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a library or framework that has a built-in function like this?

I don't know any, but it should be trivial to program it yourself:

```
function route(hard, weak, period) {
    var isThrottled = false;
    return function() {
        if (isThrottled) {
            return weak.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            isThrottled = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                isThrottled = false;
            }, period);
            return hard.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm testing it right now and it seems to work fine! Thanks, now I don't even have to use Underscore.js at all. Can you explain what .apply does here? Is it needed if either function has parameters?

Comment: [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does call the functions in the same [context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and with the same [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) as the `route`d function.

Comment: That's really useful, does something like this exist in other languages like Python or Ruby?

Comment: I haven't used any of them myself but I would expect similar mechanisms in any "powerful" language :-)